# How to detect Sitecore ECM version

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

Is there an easy way to detect the version of Sitecore ECM in a Sitecore installation?

The Sitecore solution installed is Sitecore 6.5 rev. 120427 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the package install history in the `Core database` under `/sitecore/system/Packages/Installation history/E-mail Campaign Manager`. If you have installed multiple versions then there will be multiple child entries with each revision number.

If you need to get the current running version from code then just get reflect the `FileVersionInfo`

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("Sitecore.EmailCampaign.dll");
var fvi = System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(assembly.Location);
string version = fvi.FileVersion;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. The path in the core database was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly 'hack-ish', but you could look to see what packages have already been installed via the `Installation Wizard`.  When you select a package, it gives you the version number.

Click on the `Sitecore` button, choose `Development Tools`, then `Installation Wizard`.  Choose `Browse` and then look for the email campaign manager module that was installed.  After you select it, it should show the version number information in the file name.

Caveat: This probably doesn't help if you've installed multiple versions of the ECM over time.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the file system, you can see the version of any module by looking at the properties of the corresponding DLL file (right click on file and choose Properties). This information is stored under the "Product name" and/or "Product version" property in the Details tab.

[image: Sitecore module version]